# Radix Sort Using Bitwise Shift ">>" and bitwise and "&" operators using base 8 and 4

Tags: sorting, bit-manipulation, radix

How does one go about sorting an array with the int contents {782, 40, 21}, using the Radix sort method, and utilizing bitwise shift ">>" and bitwise and "&" operators? How is this done using base 8 and 4?

Comment: You want to do a radix sort for 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

Example base 256 radix sort for 32 bit integers. std::swap() could be replaced by any swap method.

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

//  a is input array, b is working array
uint32_t * RadixSort(uint32_t * a, uint32_t *b, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // count / index matrix
size_t i,j,m,n;
uint32_t u;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = a[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        m = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = a[i];
            m = (size_t)(u>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            b[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                //  swap ptrs
    }
    return(a);
}
```